# JavaScript recursion and closure?

Tags: javascript

I have this function (sample here: http://jsbin.com/emabe4/ )

```
var a=[];
var log = document.getElementById('log');

function loop(x){

  x++;
  a.push(x);

  if (x < 10){
    log.innerHTML = log.innerHTML + "<br/>" + a;
    console.log(a);
    loop(x)
  }

}
```

As the loop calls itself recursively, the array gets longer and is written out with the inner HTML as such:

```
[1]
[1,2]
...
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Which is how I'd like it to work.

But if you look at the console log, this is what you see:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
...
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

The questions:

1) Why the discrepancy between innerHTML and console.log?

2) the console log appears to be what is actually being created and I think that's due to a closure problem, correct? If so, what's the workaround for this to do what I want it to do (the former, where I can interact with the array step-by-step as it grows each time)? I've solved this before in while loops, but not sure how to handle it here.

Comment: It appears to not work correctly in Chrome. Maybe Chrome defers the calls to console.log until after the recursion? Firefox 3.6.3 appears to work correctly.

Comment: hmm...you are right! so...why the difference when sending 'a' to log vs '"" + a' to log?

Comment: interesting...if I merely put an alert(''); in there, that's enough to get the console to log the output properly. Seems to be a timing issue between the script and the console.

Comment: regarding `"" + a` it force the generation of a temporary string and it's this string that is displayed by the log, not the array.

Comment: Interestingly, it works as expected when you remove the `log.innerHTML` line. And it doesn't work right when you put `log.innerHTML = 'x'`. So it seems like it has something to do with `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.log(a)` <del>is</del> *should be* strictly evaluated and will have the same results as the innerHTML. This can be verified (or disproved) with `console.log("" + a)`. As the post and comments indicate, this differs by browser (Chrome is lazy here, Firefox is strict).

In the case of `console.log("" + a)` it *forces* the evaluation of the object in `a` to the string representation.

There is only one `a` in all cases (and more-so, there is *only one array passed to console.log*). That is, it's not a closure problem with *the code*, but rather a problem with `console.log` deferring conversion of the object to a string representation (in Chrome). If it defers conversion until after the loop completes then the behavior would be as described as it will print out *the same object* n (10) times in a row.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome console is keeping your array around and by the time it could display it, it already changed.

I guess that it might be filled as a chrome bug, that console.log should clone it's input or convert it to string but not defer evaluation of it's arguments.

By forcing a string conversion you could even get things like that :

```
a=1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a=1,2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a=1,2,3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a=1,2,3,4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a=1,2,3,4,5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a=1,2,3,4,5,6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a=1,2,3,4,5,6,7
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP doesn't mention which browser this happening in, but this behavior has been reported in the Chromium project. See [Issue 50316](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316&q=console.log&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS). A project member reports the following:

> we evaluate array content
>   asynchronously when it has its latest
>   value

For other browsers this doesn't seem to be an issue.